# Change lock screen style on gnome classic desktop

Tags: gnome-classic, lock-screen

Is there a way to use Unity lock screen in Gnome classic desktop?

I love the way unity fades the main screen to lock the session, while I'm not  enthusiastic about the window showed by the classic windows manager.

Comment: Are you using lightdm or gdm? If you're using gdm, try changing to lightdm. I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but that might work.

Comment: this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/how-to-customize-gdm-36-login-lock.html) might help

Comment: Yes, I think that lightdm is the one that I would like to add to my Ubuntu. Do you know how to set that stuff up into gnome classic desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get install lightdm`. If it's already installed, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, and choose lightdm. You can still log in to any desktop you've install by selecting the arrow in lightdm and clicking gnome classic.

Comment: Done it, but it did not change anything... :/

Comment: What exactly is happening now? Are you logging in with lightdm or gdm, and when does the problem show up? Has it worked in the past?

Comment: He might need `unity-greeter` too.

Comment: Unity-greeter is installed. It does happen exactly the same as before. When I log in for the first time (after switching the machine on) it is lightdm interface with nice fading; when I lock the screen, it is gdm. And, it has never worked before for me (that's why in the initial question it was written "maybe it is a dumb question", but then KasiyA prefered to edit my question!).